# How to display some elements into a div modifying the width

Tags: html, css, css-position, display

I want to display the div with the filled stars on the div with the empty stars. The result that I want is to reveal the filled stars modifying the width of the div.

I try to explain better. If with a width of 100px 5 filled stars are displayed, I want to be able to set the width to 83px and display only 4,5 stars.

My problem is that now if I set a div of 83px, the last star floats under the other stars. I would like to keep the stars in a fixed position and show also portions of it.

This is my code:

```css
.rating-star {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: green;
}

.vote-container {
    position: relative;
}

.full-stars {
    position: absolute;
}

.vote,
.vote-number {
    color: green;
}

.full-stars {
  display: block;
  height: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 83px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="vote-container" id="vote-container_1">
  <span class="full-stars">
    <i class="fa rating-star fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa rating-star fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa rating-star fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa rating-star fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa rating-star fa-star"></i>
  </span>
  <i class="fa rating-star fa-star-o"></i>
  <i class="fa rating-star fa-star-o"></i>
  <i class="fa rating-star fa-star-o"></i>
  <i class="fa rating-star fa-star-o"></i>
  <i class="fa rating-star fa-star-o"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: add white-space:nowrap ... and let me find the duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add just this code in .full-stars class.

```
white-space:nowrap
```